# How do i add a maximum and minimum to a variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, max, min

I am making a menu that shows what section your on, on my website. I have 3 circles that show what section your on.

If you click on 'down', you go a section further, if you click on 'up', you go a section back.

Now i made it that it you click 'down', it adds 1 to the variable 'sectionCounter', and if you click up it removes 1 from it.

I want to add a minimum that is 1, and a max that is 3, because there are no more sections, how do i do this?

Here is my jQuery:

```
    var sectionCounter = 1;
    sectionCounter == 1;

    $('.down1').click(function() {
        var section2 = $('.section2');
        var pos = section2.offset().top;
        sectionCounter += 1;
        $('h1').html(sectionCounter);

    if (sectionCounter == 1){
        $('.count1').addClass('countActive');
    }else {
        $('.count1').removeClass('countActive');
    };


    if (sectionCounter == 2){
        $('.count2').addClass('countActive');
    }else {
        $('.count2').removeClass('countActive');
    };


    if (sectionCounter == 3){
        $('.count3').addClass('countActive');
    }else {
        $('.count3').removeClass('countActive');
    };


    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:pos},2000); // will take two seconds to scroll to the element
    });


    $('.up1').click(function() {
        var section1 = $('.section1');
        var pos2 = section1.offset().top;
        sectionCounter -= 1;
        $('h1').html(sectionCounter);

    if (sectionCounter == 1){
        $('.count1').addClass('countActive');
    }else {
        $('.count1').removeClass('countActive');
    };


    if (sectionCounter == 2){
        $('.count2').addClass('countActive');
    }else {
        $('.count2').removeClass('countActive');
    };


    if (sectionCounter == 3){
        $('.count3').addClass('countActive');
    }else {
        $('.count3').removeClass('countActive');
    };

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:pos2},2000); // will take two seconds to scroll to the element
    });
```

Comment: Side note: You don't put `;` after the block attached to a control-flow statement (`if`, `else`, `while`, `for`, `switch`). Doing so is harmless (because JavaScript has the *EmptyStatement*, which effectively means it ignores extraneous `;`s), but also pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

#### You can use an `if`

```
if (sectionCounter < 3) {
    sectionCounter += 1; // Side note: `++sectionCounter;` or `sectionCounter++;` would be more idiomatic
}
```

And similarly for the `-= 1` case:

```
if (sectionCounter > 1) {
    sectionCounter -= 1; // Side note: `--sectionCounter;` or `sectionCounter--;` would be more idiomatic
}
```

#### You can (ab)use the `&&` operator:

```
sectionCounter < 3 && ++sectionCounter;
```

And similarly for the `-= 1` case:

```
sectionCounter > 1 && --sectionCounter;
```

Those work because the right-hand operand isn't evaluated if the left-hand operand is true (or rather, [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)).

#### You can use `Math.min`/`Math.max`:

```
sectionCounter = Math.min(3, sectionCounter + 1);
```

and

```
sectionCounter = Math.max(1, sectionCounter - 1);
```

Comment: I put the last option under the  'var sectionCounter = 1;'  but this doens't seems to work for me.

Comment: @rutgervs - The point is to do this where you do `+=` and `-=`, not immediately after declaring the variable.